# How to store the entered parameters from cloudformation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, persistence, aws-cloudformation

What I want to accomplish is to store the entered parameters from a Cloudformation stack.

**For example:** Imagine having two parameters `param1` and `param2`.

I want to store the entered values either in DynamoDB, RDS Db, Etc.

**I though in SNS notification:**

[image]

**Unfortunately, the notification's payload looks as follow:**

```
StackId='arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:accountId:stack/rfdsf/b6df0100-fd18-11e7-b3ab-500c2893c0d2'
Timestamp='2018-01-19T13:00:24.774Z'
EventId='b6df9d40-fd18-11e7-b3ab-500c2893c0d2'
LogicalResourceId='rfdsf'
Namespace='accountId'
PhysicalResourceId='arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:accountId:stack/rfdsf/b6df0100-fd18-11e7-b3ab-500c2893c0d2'
PrincipalId='accountId'
ResourceProperties='null'
ResourceStatus='CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'
ResourceStatusReason='User Initiated'
ResourceType='AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'
StackName='rfdsf'
ClientRequestToken='Console-CreateStack-774eec95-c976-434c-b43b-ad3d295a0b9b'
```

As you can see, there is not any entered values.

**Is it possible to store the entered parameters into a DB?**

Comment: Would you be able to invoke an API? If so, have you looked at `GetTemplateSummary` API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_GetTemplateSummary.html?

Comment: Where will the parameters be used after storing?

Comment: @KrishnaKumarR thank you, according to the documentation that api returns metadata of my stack rather than entered values.

Comment: @RodrigoM will be used for auditing purposes.

Comment: I am sorry @Eleazar Enrique. You are right, it returns only the default values.

Comment: Have you tried the `DescribeStacks` API: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStacks.html?

Comment: Why not use the Parameter Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cloudformation there is an Outputs parameter. You can output any value that was brought into the stack, so long as you explicitly specify which parameters you want to output.

Those values will be visible in the Outputs tab of cloudformation. If you want to move them to a database, such as DynamoDB, you can use the cloudformation:describeStacks api call to get all the output values for any stack.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Rodrigigo M, You can save the params into SSM parameters store.

```
Description: "Create SSM Parameter"
Resources:
  BasicParameter:
    Type: "AWS::SSM::Parameter"
    Properties:
      Name: "param1"
      Type: "String"
      Value: "ABCD"
      Description: "SSM Parameter for running date command."
      AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z]{1,10}$"
```

Also, if you want to save these into DB, you can create a Lambda to read them and store into DynamoDb or RDS.

Comment: doesn't work for retrieving the stored parameter in another region.